# Selecting and matching 3 and 6 distinct numbers yield different numerators

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

From Discrete Mathematics by R Johnsonbaugh, problem 6.5.24.

"In the California Daily 3 game, a contestant must select three numbers among 0 to 9. One type of “box play” win requires that three numbers match in any order those randomly drawn by a lottery representative, repetitions allowed. What is the probability of choosing the winning numbers, assuming that the contestant chooses three distinct numbers?"

The answer says $\frac{3!}{10^3}$. I understand why the denominator is $10^3$ but why is the numerator $3!$ and not say $10\times9\times8$?

And if I accept the numerator $3!$ above, why does the example below not have $6!$ in the numerator? After all, in the example below, just like the one above, we match n different numbers in any order.

problem 6.5.25:
"In the Maryland Lotto game, to win the grand prize the contestant must match six distinct numbers, in any order, among the numbers 1 through 49 randomly drawn by a lottery representative. What is the probability of choosing the winning numbers?
" Answer: $\frac{1}{C(49,6)}$.

Comment: The important difference is the California draw is "repetitions allowed" (so either putting the number back in for each draw, or often these actually use three different boxes). The Maryland description doesn't really say whether the draw is the same or draws six different numbers, but the answer is correct if the draw does get six different numbers from the same box without replacement.

Comment: Thanks seems reasonable insightful. I'm just trying to understand what leads to the different numerators, $3!$ vs $1$. If Maryland allowed for "putting number back" for each draw, would the answer to Maryland then be $\frac{6!}{49^6}$, analogous to California?